# How to target local SEO to one side of our city (a group of suburbs)?

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-local-search

Our suburban tennis club website has improved its rankings on Google Perth, Western Australia, and search visibility has doubled, but website traffic has remained the same.

I appreciate that not all people in Perth will want to click through to our suburban tennis club website, as they may **not** be close to our tennis club; they may prefer a tennis club in a suburb closer to them.

Any advice is appreciated on getting more relevant local website traffic, e.g. from people closer to our suburb of Perth.

Our suburb of Perth is called Melville, BTW. So getting clicks from people in Melville and the suburbs near Melville is our goal.

Comment: I don't know much about SEO. However, if I were searching online for something located nearby, my search query would likely include the name of the community or major streets, for example. Therefore, my instinct says to incorporate these keywords into the website.

Answer (score 1):

To get more local visitors to your website you can consider the following points. (this is an example)

- Perform competition analysis + keyword analysis/research.
- Look what your competitors are doing on the first page and do it better.
- Onpage optimization, especially optimizing the landing page/target page for the desired local keywords.
- Check technical SEO aspects and adjust if necessary.
- Advanced schema markup creation for LocalBusiness.
- Optimize content for local keywords (images alt-tag, title tag, graphics, videos)
- Maps share link in the footer with [city + keyword + near me] example: "Tennis Club Perth near me" > link with map share direction link or CID+kgmid (use with caution).
- NAP with opening hours in footer (Exactly as Google outputs) (use GMB Everywhere or PlePer chrome extension)
- List your company in all relevant business directories (local-citations) with correct NAP.
- Get guest posts from local and regional bloggers. Example: Blogs about tennis, sports, newspapers, city guides.
- Write a local press release
- Option: place local ads

To rank for the terms "near me" you definitely need to look at your competition.

What you can also do is to calculate the average usage of the keyword "near me" of the top 3 competitors and then use this accordingly often in the H2, H3 headlines as well as in the body text.

I hope that could steer you something in the direction of what is needed. Of course, depending on the industry and market situation, customized individual optimizations are required. I would recommend applying to an SEO expert who can help you with the search engine optimization.

EDIT:
The position for individual suburbs could be improved by creating blog posts about the suburb or a silo structure for a new category.

For example, Perth < suburbs (Melville) < tennis stores < tennis equipment.

Important search terms for the suburb could then be placed here as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question (ie group of suburbs).  Its also self promotion.  And  probably came from chatgpt

Comment: That you classify my experience and help as an automated ChatGPT response, I take as a compliment. I am just trying to offer my help here. The above points are based on experience from many projects.

Comment: You're right, I didn't explain more about the suburbs. There is a reason for that. Because unnecessary pages that only serve the suburbs offer little benefit to the user, in my experience. The points above relate to creating a holistic local optimization for "Perth and the suburb of "Melville". The above points can help the website do this.